# Android app - Chrome extension communication

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to have my Android app communicate with a Chrome extension where a user is signed into both with their Google account. Preferably I want to avoid having an intermediate server and rely on an existing service bus.

I had assumed Google Cloud Messaging would fit the bill as it can be implemented in both Android and Chrome but it seems to stop short of allowing direct communication without a 3rd party server.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean wireless communication or is USB also an option ? How about Bluetooth or wifi communication over you local network ?

Comment: No, over the internet but via some sort of messaging service. For example, a service where I can post requests from my app, and pick them up in my extension. Like a message queuing system, but internet-based.

Comment: you should take a look on Pushbullet.

Comment: Pushbullet, I believe, uses Google Cloud Messaging on the Android and Chrome extension side, but with their own servers in the middle. I'm hoping there is a solution that doesn't involve any intermediate servers (other than those that handle the messaging obviously)

Comment: I still don't get why GCM is not suitable. Do you want to essentialy implement GCM on your own server ?

Comment: I don't want a server involved at all! At least, not one of mine. I don't think it is possible to push a message to GCM on Android to be received by an extension in Chrome (and vice versa). Or is it?

Comment: @Barguast: Sorry, I just got what you want. No, it seems not to be possible without using an application server.

Comment: Shame, but good to know. Thanks for your help.